# Should i keep a local copy of remote database?

Tags: android, mysql, database, sqlite, mobile

I am working on an application that will, basically, allow people to create, join and manage groups of other people. The people within the groups can also message each other.

I have been wondering which path would be better:

1. Keep a remote database with all the information, including messages sent to and from users. And have the app query the server every time it needs information. Even information it has seen before.
2. Keep a remote database with all the information, including messages sent to and from users. Also keep a local copy of the remote database and just keep it synced with the remote database. Whenever the app needs to query for information, it does a query to see if the local table is up to date. If it is not up to date, it updates the table and runs the query on the local table. This way it will keep a local copy and the app will have fast queries when there is not an update to the remote table.

   - What is generally done with mobile applications and remote databases?
   - Would it be "bad practice" if i just did number 1?

Comment: Interesting discussion. I would say caching the messages on the device is a good idea. But syncing the database with the device may not be very scalable, since it will require too much information to be saved with many users.

Answer (score 3):

From my point of view, in most cases, the database in the mobile is just a cache of the real database, the one in the server. So, my suggestion will be to keep locally all data that you need syncing with the server. This allows you to show information even when no connection and show something to the user while the info is updated.

Also, this approach makes the local data volatile without risk, as it's stored in the server. So:

- All info is in the server
- With a background process (service, thread, intentservice, whatever best suits you) you sync this information with the local database
- UI is always showing info from local database

Of course, this is a very general approach, and needs to be examined for each case as different situations may need different approaches.

Answer (score 2):

My base response is that I would keep the data in one place and access it remotely unless there is a major reason to keep it locally.  There would have to be extenuating circumstances to mandate that I keep a copy of the data locally.  Just make sure your queries are accurate and concise.  Don't pull over more data than you need to.
However, you can have a subset of data kept locally.  Items that are specific to the user (like messages), but keeping data that is not relevant just adds overhead and bloat.

Comment: Why wouldn't you save the messages sent between the users locally? It is a waste of bandwidth not to do that. All big message apps like Whatsapp, Kik, Telegram etc. save messages locally.

Comment: Depending on what you are moving around, you can really burn up space.  Without knowing what kind of data you are looking at it is hard to give a specific answer.  If you are only talking about storing information relevant to the local system then yes, but if you are talking about a full database of information when only a small percentage of it is being used, you are wasting bandwidth and space.

Also, if the information is being updated by other sources then you are spending a lot of time and effort making sure that information is kept current in many locations from a mobile perspective.

Comment: Good input, and I agree that not the complete database should be saved locally. The messages, however, should probably not be saved on a server at all. You could just relay the messages via the server to the different users of the application without saving them (privacy issues). The users would then have a local copy of their exchanged messages which they can view at any time. If one user would be off-line you could temporarily cache the messages on the server.

Comment: In most cases legality would say that the messages should be stored.  Depending on your industry you have to watch that aspect.  And yes there would need to be the ability to cache messages and have them automatically download when reconnecting.

Comment: It is of course not possible to determine if messages should be stored without insight in the use case. But do you still think messages shouldn't be stored locally? Why then? as stated earlier, all the big messaging applications **do** store messages on the device.

Comment: Messages, yes.  They should be stored locally.  You could even offer the ability to select information to store locally incase you are in an area with limited network access.  But not the whole database.

Comment: Agreed. I think you should edit your answer, because the question explicitly mentions messages. If prolink007 also agrees he can then accept your answer.