# How to connect mobile app to database

Tags: java, php, android, database

I created a basic barcode scanner app with Java and Android Studio (on my Mac paradoxically). In this app, I simply uploaded (manually) some photos of barcodes to Android Studio in the `.../app/src/main/res/drawable` folder from my desktop and then I am sending one of these photos each time to `Google Mobile Vision Barcode API`.    I receive from the API the data represented from the barcode and I simply print the data on the screen of the Android emulator.
The `MainActivity.java` script of this app is the following:

```
package *********************;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.util.SparseArray;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.Frame;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode.Barcode;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode.BarcodeDetector;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        ImageView myImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgview);
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                getApplicationContext().getResources(),
                R.drawable.image);
        myImageView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);

        TextView txtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtContent);

        BarcodeDetector detector =
                new BarcodeDetector.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                        .setBarcodeFormats(Barcode.DATA_MATRIX | Barcode.QR_CODE | Barcode.CODE_128)
                        .build();
        if(!detector.isOperational()){
            txtView.setText("Could not set up the detector!");
            return;
        }

        Frame frame = new Frame.Builder().setBitmap(myBitmap).build();
        SparseArray<Barcode> barcodes = detector.detect(frame);

        Barcode thisCode = barcodes.valueAt(0);
        txtView.setText(thisCode.rawValue);

    }
```

Now I want to use the retrieved data from the Barcode API, send them to (a server and to) a database and retrieve some details stored in this database about the product that has this barcode.

**What is the most appropriate way to make my Java app to communicate with a database?**

Personally, I am pretty confident in creating a MySQL database and sending back and forth data with PHP.

However, I am not really sure how to connect a script written in Java (which scans barcodes) to a database.

Comment: If you using mobile APP it is recommended to send/retreive your data by the one of web service (eg. REST) instead of directly connecting to the database.

Answer (score 0):

**It really depends on your use case.**

**Possibilities:**

1- Make your own database (Sqlite) in your Android App. This means you have to synchronize via web services, with your server's database, whenever you see fit.

***Steps:***

- a) Use an [ORM](https://www.sitepoint.com/5-best-android-orms/) to connect to your local database and to relational map your tables with your classes.
- b) Use web service to synchronise your classes (eg. [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/)) with your server's database, via an API.

2- Only use the 'b' part of the 1-st step to save your data to remote database, on-fly (as soon as data is submmited)

So you actually CAN (b), but connecting to remote database immediately as the data gets submitted is really bad(in my opinion). For many reasons. Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24342403/should-i-keep-a-local-copy-of-remote-database#answer-24343076).

In the end, it all comes down to your choice and the best suit for your app's use-case.

Best